# Django app per websitemenu item?

Tags: python, django, django-apps

I have a question about aesthetic website like apple.com for example. I see the website menu items Mac, iPad, iPhone, etc...

My question is : Would you consider each menu item as a Django app or all menu items are considered by the same Django App ?

Thanks for the help everyone

Comment: Your question is a little bit too broad. Applications can be structured in many different ways.

Comment: @serg give one good example.

Answer (score 1):

As said Serg Chernata, your question is a little bit too broad. But if I understand your question I could give you my mind :

**1) The navbar website item**

The navbar website could be write with `Bootstrap 3`. It's possible to make lots of navigations menu and Bootstrap is very usefull to do that :

https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

You can make this kind of things (of course, `CSS` can be used in order to change the aesthetic from `navbar`)

[image]

**2) Menu items**

I think that you should develop one application per item. It's easier to get a base template and add some independent elements to each item. If you want to modify just one of them, you should change just the corresponding `HTML` template and not all files.

Hopfully my answer can help you ;)